# passport.authenticate (local strategy) not able to take req body username and password and returned message (“Missing Credentials')

Tags: node.js, passport.js

many hours spent on reading books, passport.org and similar issues in stackoverflow.  However, still had no clue why login failed using passport to authenticate with simple local strategy of username and password. passport.autheticate came back stating with info="missing credential" and user='false".

before stepping into passport.authenticate, confirmed that req.body had the right user info of username and password from Angular.

Besides, user registration using passport worked, however, using same username and password was not able to log in.

Below pls find code and thanks for any help in advance.

```
App.js (code associated with user registration and login)
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var authenticate = require('./lib-general/authenticate');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var User = require('./model/user');
var app = express();
const util = require('util');
var debug = require('debug')('http'),
    http = require('http'),
name ='pIn3-server';

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) );
app.use(session({
  name: 'session-id',
  secret: config.secretKey,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  store: new FileStore()
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', usersRouter);
```

authenticate.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../model/user');
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('../config.js');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate(),{passReqToCallback : true}));  
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

console.log("before getToken");

exports.getToken = function(user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey,
        {expiresIn: 3600});
};

var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
console.log("after jwtFromRequest - extract JWT");
console.log(opts.jwtFromRequest);
opts.secretOrKey = config.secretKey;
console.log("after secretOrKey");
console.log(opts.secretOrKey);

exports.jwtPassport = passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,
    (jwt_payload, done) => {
        console.log("JWT payload: ", jwt_payload);
        User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._id}, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            else if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            }
            else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
    
exports.verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});
```

Users.js (user router)

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var User = require('../model/user');
var passport = require('passport');
var authenticateMy = require('../lib-general/authenticate');  // use my to distinguish from passport authenticate
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var cors = require('./cors');
var userRouter = express.Router();
userRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseClient = require('mongoose');  /* this is important  */

console.log("step into router users");

/*ensure if it from right port of whitelist in cors:3000, 3443, 4200 */
userRouter.options('*', cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); } )
/* Get users listing. */

userRouter.get('/',cors.cors,function(req,res,next){
  res.send('respond with a resource')
});

userRouter.post('/signup', cors.corsWithOptions,(req, res, next) => {
  console.log('2.0.0.1 - at register',req.body);
  let newUser = new User( {
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      role: req.body.role,
      remember: req.body.remember }); // from book
  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user) => { 
  
    if(err) {
      console.log('2.0.0.2 - at register',err,user);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({err: err});
    }
    else {
        console.log('2.0.1 - at register',req.body);
        user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json({err: err});
            return ;
        }
  
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({success: true, status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

userRouter.post('/login', cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('2.0.4 - at login',req.body);
  
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user , info) => {
    console.log('2.0.5 - at login', user, info);

    if (err)
      return next(err);

    if (!user) {
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({success: false, status: 'Login Unsuccessful!', err: info});
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('2.0.6 - at req.login',user);
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({success: false, status: 'Login Unsuccessful!', err: 'Could not log in user!'});          
      }

      var token = authenticateMy.getToken({_id: req.user._id});
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({success: true, status: 'Login Successful!', token: token});
    }); 
  }) (req, res, next);
});

userRouter.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in userRouter logout code')
  if (req.session) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.clearCookie('session-id');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
  else {
    console.log('in userRouter log out ')
    var err = new Error('You are not logged in!');
    err.status = 403;
    next(err);
  }
  
});
```

Comment: any hint pls - is this Q too challenging or it is too dumb?  While I am new to Angular/node.js, I have lots of programming and IT experience.  In my opinion, a good programming language or app should be easy to debug or give good hint to user for solving issue quickly.

Comment: Issue has now been resolved after learning a hard way.  Issue was not with NodeJs. It was to do with how username and password were sent from Angular.  'user' was {} that caused the problem.  After taking it off to "return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(baseURL + 'users/login', user)", passport.authentication worked.  Hope this can help others.